# Why does mysqli_num_rows always return 1 when using SQL AVG() function?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a voting system and am experiencing an incompatibility problem between the `SELECT AVG` function and `mysqli_num_rows`.

When using `AVG()`, `mysqli_num_rows` always returns the number 1. However, I need the real number of rows for my if statement. How can I do that?

```
$consulta_nota_geral = "SELECT * , avg(comp1) as competencia1 , avg(comp2) as competencia2 , avg(comp3) as competencia3 , avg(comp4) as competencia4 , avg(comp5) as competencia5  FROM votos WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'";
$consulta_nota_geral_conect = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta_nota_geral) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta_nota_geral_conect) > 0) {
    //other code here
}
```

Comment: Side note: Your code stands to be open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by incompatibility you mean that `mysqli_num_rows()` returns 1. It is because `AVG()` groups the rows into one and then computes the average.

If you want to get the real number of rows, you can use `COUNT(*)`.

So, your query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_rows, avg(comp1) as competencia1 , avg(comp2) as competencia2 , avg(comp3) as competencia3 , avg(comp4) as competencia4 , avg(comp5) as competencia5  FROM votos WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'
```

Then, you would use `mysqli_fetch_row()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get the data.

```
$consulta_nota_geral = "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_rows, avg(comp1) as competencia1 , avg(comp2) as competencia2 , avg(comp3) as competencia3 , avg(comp4) as competencia4 , avg(comp5) as competencia5  FROM votos WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'";
$consulta_nota_geral_conect = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta_nota_geral) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_nota_geral_conect);
if($data["number_of_rows"] > 0) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it was very informative. The code now recognizes 0 rows, however, it now recognizes nothing.
I configured an echo to know the return of the sql and it is blank ...
I do not know what that can be

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: number_of_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\aula\index.php on line 34

Comment: <code>consulta_nota_geral = "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_rows, avg(comp1) as competencia1 , avg(comp2) as competencia2 , avg(comp3) as competencia3 , avg(comp4) as competencia4 , avg(comp5) as competencia5  FROM votos WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'";
$consulta_nota_geral_conect = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta_nota_geral) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$numero_linhas = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta_nota_geral_conect);
if($numero_linhas["number_of_rows"] > 0) {
    echo $numero_linhas['number_of_rows'];
}else  {
    $nota_geral_total = 'Seja o primeiro a votar';
}</code>

Comment: Genhis, my code is like this right now. There is something wrong? I will come at dawn doing this and I do not know if I'm good with my head, maybe I'm committing some hesitation

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row()`. The difference is that, `mysqli_fetch_row()` uses indices while `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` uses column names / aliases.

Comment: OH MY GOD,, RUN !!!
THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
but show this erro mensage   Illegal string offset 'number_of_rows'

Comment: :( my code is exactly 
$consulta_nota_geral_conect = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta_nota_geral) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$nota_geral = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_nota_geral_conect);
$numero_linhas = $nota_geral['number_of_rows'];
    if ($numero_linhas['number_of_rows'] > 0) {
    $nota_geral_total = $nota_geral['competencia1'] + $nota_geral['competencia2'] + $nota_geral['competencia3'] + $nota_geral['competencia4'] + $nota_geral['competencia5'];
    if ($nota_geral['competencia1'] == 0) {
        $texto_comp1 = 'você tirou 0';

Comment: See this? `$numero_linhas = $nota_geral['number_of_rows']` and then `if($numero_linhas['number_of_rows'] > 0)` ... `$numero_linhas` is the number, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The sql returns one row because it's using aggregate functions (avg). If you add a `count(*)` to the select, it will return that with the sql results.